# Cannot authenticate via Postman (Bearer token)

Tags: json, api, rest, postman, bearer-token

So I am trying around with an application that I did not code, and I am quite new to REST APIs etc, so I am having some issues with that.

From my front-end Next.js application I am sending an Axios request to the backend with a Bearer token header

```
const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    method,
    url: `${BASE_URL}${url}`,
    headers: isFormData ? { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } : {},
    data: isFormData ? params : ( params ? { ...params } : null ),
    validateStatus: function (status) {
      return status >= 200 && status < 300 // default
    }
  }

  config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${userStore.token}`
```

Everything works, so if a user is authenticated and has the token in the userStore the request is successful and the backend responds with the given json data for a certain api route.

[Postman Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXDp0.png)

Though when I try to fetch the json data directly from the API route in Postman, and provide the Authorization header for this request, I get an error not authorized response from the backend. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

try selecting 'bearer token' under authorization and give the token directly.

[image]